# How to prevent objects to jump off platforms?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have a game set up like this:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, '', {preload: preload, create: create, update: update});
var platforms;
var aGroup;

function preload() {
    game.load.image('platform', 'img/platform.png');
    game.load.image('a', 'img/a.png');
}

function create() {
    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
    platforms = game.add.group();
    platforms.enableBody = true;
    var platform = platforms.create(100, 100, 'platform');

    aGroup = game.add.group();
    aGroup.enableBody = true;

    platforms.forEach(function(item) {
        item.body.immovable = true;
        aGroup.create(item.x, item.y - 32, 'a');
    }, this);

    aGroup.forEach(function(a) {
        a.body.velocity.x = 100;
    }
}

function update() {
    game.physics.arcade.collide(aGroup, platforms);

    aGroup.forEach(function(a) {
          if(a.body.blocked.right) {
              a.body.velocity.x = -100;
          }
        else if(a.body.blocked.left) {
            a.body.velocity.x = 100;
        }, this);
    }
}
```

Currently I can check if `a` is colliding with the world boundaries and if it does it changes direction. Right now when `a` reaches the end of the platform it just falls down. I want `a` to change direction when it reaches the end of the platform.

How can I do it?

Comment: Have them collide with invisible geometry. Have a conditional in the position updating. There are a hundred ways to do this.

Comment: I do not understand very well, you have a sprite on top of another one that is a platform (like Mario Bross on a brick) and do you want that when it reaches the end of that platform it does not fall or get out but it takes an opposite direction?

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. I think it's best to use invisible sprites for this.